# Solution Import Failed with no error in the downloaded log, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

When importing a CRM 2011 unmanaged solution from one CRM 2011 instance to another CRM 2011 instance, the solution import failed at 99.87% and no detail on what caused the import to fail reported in the downloaded log file.

All components processed except for the last two: Root Components Insertion and Dependencies Calculation.

How to troubleshoot such incident? Is there anywhere else CRM stores more details on how the import solution job failed?

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable CRM tracing and try the import again. You can only do this with an on-premise installation however.

This will hopefully give you some more information that can point you in the right direction. Unfortunately it is possible it won't give any meaningful detail about how to go about fixing the issue!

You can use this tool to easily enable tracing on your CRM box http://crmdiagtool2011.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, tracing was enabled and somehow I missed the real error: "Crm Exception: Message: Import failed, ErrorCode: -2147188706, InnerException: Microsoft.Crm.Tools.ImportExportPublish.ImportGenericException: Import failed ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query."

Comment: It appears some infra guy dropped the memory allocation to the DB server from 32GB to 2GB for 'good reason'